Cloned .net MAUI windows project debugs but does not run(show) but runs in background
I cloned my .NET MAUI project from github in my pc (I had factory reset my pc and cloned the project to debug it), the build is successful but it does not run. Task manager shoes the app running in background. I had a .gitignore file that ignored bins and objs. Could it be causing the problem?
I tried to run/ debug the project but it builds and run in background.

Can you right-click the solution file, and go to the Configuration Manager. There verify all the checkboxes are checked (including Deploy)?

Yes, both checkboxes (build , deploy) are checked

Create a brand new empty project and move the code from the original project into the new one, then to run it?
